# delete Scrapy Cache?

Tags: caching, scrapy

I am trying to remove cache by deleting .scrapy folder. Usually it works but now when I run my spider it always gets the cached responses. I have no idea where it gets them from since the folder is deleted. I already tried to change spider name / folder name / make a new project and paste code in it etc.

Even more puzzling is that [Process Monitor](http://downloads.tomsguide.com/Process-Monitor,0301-7078.html) tool shows me live the cache files being opened from that empty folder WITHOUT being created first. The cache files are just being opened and closed but I don't see them in the folder. I don't see them in that folder before and also not seeing them there after running the spider. They are not hidden , show hidden files option is checked.

The only thing I can imagine is that Scrapy somehow keeps them in a database and shows them as taken from the cache folder. But in this case why doesn't process manager show the files being created and deleted? After 3 hours of renaming and pasting the project around in new folders I am going crazy here, the cache still hangs to it.

**Update:** I've applied a filter in process monitor and I can see the files being created but I can't see them being deleted (I used SetDispositionInformationFiles to see the deleted ones). Also folder size is really small (20KB) so unless windows reports wrong there is no way my giant cache is taken from there.

Leaving Process Manager and the invisible cache files aside ... what other methods do I have to see where Scrapy takes the cache from? (I can't just disable cache, I need the cache feature, I just have to discard the old cache)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was just because I had dont_filter set to True and instead of same link over and over instead of differnt links so it wasn't getting 5K links but the same link 5K times.
 So no Scrapy mysterious behaviour just my carelessness.Big life lesson here :D